# plot a matrix with c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to plot a matrix in c#?
Currently I'm making a M file in program & open it in MATLAB then in MATLAB graph it using:

```
surface (T)
shading interp
```

NOTE that T is my Matrix.
And the plot looks like:
 [Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vGtn.jpg)

Is it possible to graph something like this with c#? my program is in console.

EDIT: Is there an example of plotting a matrix anywhere to start with it?

Comment: Yes, it will be very hard though. You will have to create a window and probably end up setting each individual pixel. It will be better if you buy some graphical tool. But you should really consider using Mathlab if anyway possible

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question: yes it is possible.

A few considerations:

- Switch your application to WinForms
- Make sure your matrix makes sense in the C# application, meaning it is a matrix of acceptable colors
- You are probably going to have to draw using a control's [canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx)

Have fun!

Comment: Forms can be launched from a console app.

Comment: Okey I'll  switch to WinForms.But how should I write that in winforms? what is the code?

Comment: @MrFox Yes, sure, but why should it be a Console Application in the first place?

Comment: @bunNyBug The considerations should get you started. Sorry, no code for you today :) Unless, you get started, try things on your own and come back with where you are stuck

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro Is there an example of plotting a matrix anywhere to start with it?

Comment: @MrFox Is there an example of plotting a matrix anywhere to start with it?

Comment: @bunNyBug I don't know why you ask me, but I found something. It only has drawing lines (that's hard enough in C#), but maybe you can expand it to the crazy difficult graphs Mathlab will draw.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32836/A-simple-C-library-for-graph-plotting